# PHP: Second query does not work

Tags: php, mysql

Via post I send values to a php file that contains the following code:

```
// Prepare values for database
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$event_title = $db -> real_escape_string($_POST['create_title_hidden']);
$event_type = $db -> real_escape_string($_POST['create_type_hidden']);
$event_town = $db -> real_escape_string($_POST['create_town_hidden']);

// 1. Identify users_id
$results = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
while ($result = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $users_id = $result['id'];
}
// 2. Identify towns_id
$query = "SELECT * FROM towns WHERE town='$event_town'";
// Do Search
$results = $db -> query($query);
while ($result = $results -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $towns_id = $result['id'];  
}
```

My problem: The second query does not work, i.e. I cannot get the town_id.

I already checked my error log, there is no such error message.

Maybe there is something I forgot to include? Is it possible two have two different queries one after another in a php script?

**EDITED:**

Here comes my frontend with the form:

```
<form id="form_create_event" method="post" action="system/upload_event_tourist.php">
        <p>
            You can now create the event:
        </p>

        <!-- Forms cannot be nested inside forms, that's why the input fields from first view
        need to be inserted into hidden input fields via jquery that will be transferred
        via post to upload_event_tourist.php -->
        <input type="hidden" id="create_title_hidden" name="create_title_hidden">
        <input type="hidden" id="create_type_hidden" name="create_type_hidden">
        <input type="hidden" id="create_start_hidden" name="create_start_hidden">
        <input type="hidden" id="create_end_hidden" name="create_end_hidden">
        <input type="hidden" id="create_picturepath_hidden" name="create_picturepath_hidden">
        <input type="hidden" id="create_meetingpoint_hidden" name="create_meetingpoint_hidden">
        <input type="hidden" id="create_description_hidden" name="create_description_hidden">

        <a href="#" class="button button_create_event">CREATE EVENT</a>
        <input type="submit" id="submit_create_event" name="submit_create_event">

    </form>
    <!-- #form_create_event -->
        <script>
            // Load form details into hidden input fields and Simulate click on submit
            $('.button_create_event').on('click', function() {

                // load form details into hidden input fields
                var event_title = $('#create_title').val();
                var event_type = $('#create_type').val();
                var event_town = $('#create_town').val();
                var event_start = $('#create_start').val();
                var event_end = $('#create_end').val();
                var event_picturepath = $('#create_picturepath').val();
                var event_meetingpoint = $('#create_meetingpoint').val();
                var event_description = $('#create_description').val();




                $('#create_title_hidden').val(event_title);
                 $('#create_type_hidden').val(event_type);
                $('#create_town_hidden').val(event_town);
                $('#create_start_hidden').val(event_start);
                $('#create_end_hidden').val(event_end);
                $('#create_picturepath_hidden').val(event_picturepath);
                $('#create_meetingpoint_hidden').val(event_meetingpoint);
                $('#create_description_hidden').val(event_description);



                $('#form_create_event').submit();

            });

        </script>
```

Comment: Try `echo $query;` to see if the query is what you want it to be?

Comment: Requisite rant: SQL injection, blah, blah, blah....

Comment: Can you confirm $event_town has valid data?  What happens when you run that query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Does the towns table have a field named `id`?

Comment: @ChrisWillard I just entered SELECT * FROM towns WHERE town='Rimini' and yes, i get the desired result... what could the problem be?

Comment: @JohnBupit: yes, the towns table has a field named id

Comment: There should be no problem in running two queries within a single database connection with MySQL. Maybe your problem relies on the values coming to and from the query. Have you checked your error logs? Anything there related to this issue? Please confirm that "$event_town" has the correct value to pass to the 2nd query. Also confirm that your "towns" table has both the column "town" and "id". Lastly, check that the 2nd query actually returns results for "$event_town" (maybe test it directly with phpmyadmin or another gui).

Comment: Then, try `var_dump`ing `$event_town`, and the `$query`.

Comment: Also, I just changed the order of the queries, but still: only the users_id is displayed, but not the towns_id

Comment: You can't get the field `town_id` but accesing an `id` ?

Comment: I just var_dumpped both the `$query` and `$towns_id` and get the following result: `string(33) "SELECT * FROM towns WHERE town=''" NULL`

Comment: @KentMiller Add echo $event_town; before your queries.  Does it show anything?  If not, you're not passing the variable correclty from your form.  Spelling error, perhaps?

Comment: Does `NULL` give you any hints?

Comment: I just updated my question and added the frontend. The weird thing: all other values are transferred succesfully, only the town name somehow not

Comment: I solved it!!! I forget a hidden input field for the town name... thanks guys for your advice anyway

Answer (score 0):

Trace out your variables.

```
$_POST['create_town_hidden']
```

is assigned by:

```
$('#create_town_hidden').val(event_town);
```

which calls the variable event_town.  That variable is set here:

```
var event_town = $('#create_town').val();
```

which is supposed to select something with an id of 'create_town', **but there is no element with that ID in your HTML**.  Fix that, and your problem is solved.